# Using a function as domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can I do something like this:

$f : S \mapsto A$, function $f$ maps the set $S$ into set $A$.

$u : f \mapsto B$, function $u$ maps the codomain of $f$ into set $B$.

Is this notation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one normally distinguishes the notation $f\colon S \to A$ (with no bar on the arrow), to indicate that $f$ is a function with domain $S$ and target $A$, from $f\colon x \mapsto \mathrm{something}(x)$ (with a bar on the arrow), to indicate that $f$ maps $x\in S$ to some particular expression of $x$ (for example, $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$: note the two different shapes of the arrow).

With that out of the way, in set-theoretical orthodoxy, using $f$ as a set is supposed to mean the graph of $f$ (i.e., the set of pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in S$ and $y\in A$ such that $y = f(x)$), so *formally*, a function $u\colon f \to B$ should be a function taking such a pair $(x,y)$ to an element of $B$; and, in practice, that is more or less equivalent to giving a function $S \to B$ (i.e., from the *domain* $S = \mathrm{dom}(f)$ of $f$, to $B$).

So, if you want a function from the *target* $A = \mathrm{cod}(f)$ of $f$, to $B$, you should explicitly write $u\colon\mathrm{cod}(f)\to B$ or whatever notation you prefer for the target (of course, the notation $\mathrm{cod}(f)$ should be introduced at some point).

Comment: Well, if $f$ is not surjective, then a function $f\to B$ does not contain enough information to determine a function $\operatorname{Codom}f\to B$. What one can get in a natural way would be a function $\operatorname{Rng} f \to B$.